# Can't compile Xamarin android project with StructureMap in release mode

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, structuremap

Create a blank android project `Blank App (Android)` in Visual Studio then add the following nuget packages
NETStandard.Library 1.6.1
StructureMap 4.5.2

Now try to compile the project in release mode.
I get the following error:

```
Using "LinkAssemblies" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Build.Tasks.dll".
Task "LinkAssemblies"
  LinkAssemblies Task
    UseSharedRuntime: False
    MainAssembly: obj\Release\linksrc\App2.dll
    OutputDirectory: obj\Release\android\assets\
    OptionalDestinationDirectory:
    I18nAssemblies:
    LinkMode: SdkOnly
    LinkSkip:
    LinkDescriptions:
    ResolvedAssemblies:
      obj\Release\linksrc\App2.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\Java.Interop.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\Mono.Android.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.Core.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.IO.Compression.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.Net.Http.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.Xml.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\mscorlib.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\StructureMap.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.Runtime.Loader.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.Runtime.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.Threading.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.Collections.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.Reflection.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.Linq.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\Mono.Security.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.IO.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.Threading.Tasks.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.Linq.Expressions.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.Globalization.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.AppContext.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.IO.FileSystem.dll
      obj\Release\linksrc\System.Console.dll
    EnableProguard: False
    ProguardConfiguration:
    DumpDependencies: False
    LinkOnlyNewerThan:
    HttpClientHandlerType:
    TlsProvider:
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1577,5): error MSB4018: The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1577,5): error MSB4018: Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Boolean StructureMap.Graph.AssemblyFinder/<FindAssemblies>
  d__1::MoveNext()' in assembly: 'StructureMap.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext::get_Default()
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1577,5): error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod(MethodReference reference)
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1577,5): error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1577,5): error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1577,5): error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1577,5): error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1577,5): error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1577,5): error MSB4018:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1577,5): error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1577,5): error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1577,5): error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1577,5): error MSB4018:    at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1577,5): error MSB4018:    at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, LinkContext& context)
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1577,5): error MSB4018:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1577,5): error MSB4018:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1577,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1577,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
Done executing task "LinkAssemblies" -- FAILED.
Done building target "_LinkAssembliesShrink" in project "App2.csproj" -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
```

In debug mode it compiles as expected but i guess the LinkAssemblies task does not run then.

I'm using Xamarin 4.6.0.297 and Visual Studio 2015.

Is this an issue in `StructureMap` or `Xamarin`?

Comment: Did you try changing the linking option to not linking at all ?

Comment: @saketkumar When i set Linking to None it compiles, what does Linking do?

Comment: Linker sometime could be very aggressive , it is supposed to remove the unused code from various  assemblies . 
But it makes the judgement on the compile time use of the code . So anywhere if some code is used through reflection it can't judge as this is runtime and it might remove that part of code leading to the problem you are facing .

Comment: If that helps let me know I would add that as an answer with some additional info so that further people can be helped when  they face linker related problem .

Comment: Changing the linker to `None` is not a complete solution but rather a workaround and will bloat your app size. You should look into linkskipping this assembly: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/#linkskip or creating a custom linker configuration: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/custom_linking/

Comment: @JonDouglas i changed back the value of Linker to `SDK only` then i edited the project file, searched for `<AndroidLinkMode>SdkOnly</AndroidLinkMode>` and added `<AndroidLinkSkip>StructureMap;System.Runtime.Loader</AndroidLinkSkip>` but i still get the same error?

Comment: when u create the APK, what are apk size with all the options ?
if u find difference is less than 5 MB , simply u don't need to care .

Comment: @saketkumar with `None` set i get a APK of 40 MB so yes that would work, but a smaller file would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update:

The seems to be an issue with the Linker and different versions of NetStandard Library. `StructureMap` is setup as a supporting  .Net45, NetStandard 1.3 and NetStandard 1.5 in the nuget, when added NetStandard Lib 1.6 is being brought in and **unless you update the packages to NetStandard Lib 2.0** (and its matching libraries), you will receive the `Mono.Cecil` error:

```
Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext::get_Default()
```

Note: I'm not sure if this is a problem with `Mono.Cecil`, the way `StructureMap` is packaged or the way Xamarin handles the nuget references...

#### `LinkDescription`:

A linker configuration like the following will get you around the issue:

```
<linker>
        <assembly fullname="StructureMap">
                <namespace fullname="StructureMap.*" />
        </assembly>
</linker>
```

Just add an XML file to your project with the contents from above and assign a build action of `LinkDescription` to it.

Note: Using `AndroidLinkSkip` to skip the assembly will not work...

Comment: Sadly this did not help, i also tried to add `System.Runtime.Loader` the same way but same error during linking.

Comment: @Peter I just tried it with a new project, added `StructureMap` to it, created a structuremap `Container` so something is referencing it, added the above LinkDescription file and it compiles and archives fine in Release mode with Linker set to `All` or `SDK`

Comment: do you get the same error when you don't have the xml file?

Comment: @Peter Yes, the same `Mono.Cecil` as yours (I know that error by heart ;-)

Comment: I can't get it to work.. i added a new xml file named `Linker.xml` pressed ctrl + a, and pasted you content. Changed the `Build Action` to `LinkDescription` then i added the following line in `MainActivity.cs` `var c = new StructureMap.Container();`. Compile it but i still get the same error.

Comment: @Peter I wonder if it a xamarin version issue with the NETStandard lib, create a new droid project add StructureMap after that update all packages so netstandard lib is at 2.0, then switch to release mode (linker sdk or all) and compile (with no LinkDescription file)

Comment: @Peter I looked at it a *little* more, but could not tell what is at fault... I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For me, adding a `LinkDescription` file, using `AndroidLinkToSkip`, and updating to .NETStandard 2.0 all did not work. Instead, I downgraded StructureMap to 4.4.0 as suggested by https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/pull/597. That seems to have resolved the issue